# Vue JS removeEventListener not working. Why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

```
const options = {
  offset: -50
};

export default {
  name: 'BarMenu',
  data() {
    return {
      scrollingDirection: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    cssClasses() {
      return {
        hidden: this.scrollingDirection === 'down'
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.onScroll();
  },
  methods: {
    scrollToIngredients() {
      return this.$scrollTo(document.getElementById('ingredients-inside-content'), 600, options);
    },
    scrollToRecipes() {
      return this.$scrollTo(document.getElementById('similar-recipes'), 600, options);
    },
    scrollToComments() {
      return this.$scrollTo(document.getElementById('comments'), 600, options);
    },
    onScroll() {
      let lastScrollTop = 0;

      const handler = () => {
        let st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        if (st > lastScrollTop) {
          this.scrollingDirection = 'down';
        } else {
          this.scrollingDirection = 'up';
        }
        lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st;
      };

      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handler, false);
      window.addEventListener("scroll", handler, false);
    }
  },
}
```

This line is not working, why? `window.removeEventListener("scroll", handler, false);`
I tried all approaches: arrow function, function declaration, etc. But that event listener is not removing at all.

Comment: You remove the handler and in the next line you add it again. Is that really what you want? Please be more specific.

Comment: `handler` won't be the same `handler` every time `scroll` is run - therefore if your code is trying to remove the old handler and replace it, then it won't work - you could make `handler` a method instead (make it an ordinary function though, not an `arrow function` - though, why you'd want to change the handler to the same code every time you run onScroll is a mystery

Comment: I want to remove this event listener, when component destroyed. I tried to perform it inside beforeDestroy lifecycle hook, but its not working.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, in the end, I solved it with another alternative, adding the `once` option in the parameters of the `addEventListener` function that removes it automatically and it was valid for me, in the case can help you check the [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've slightly overcomplicated your logic. Like what Bravo has mentioned in the comment, you will need a static reference to the handler for it to be unbound: you can simply declare it as a component method. Here's how you can update your code:

1. Use `onScroll()` method to handle the logic on scroll. You simply pass this method reference in your add/remove event listener
2. You should cache your `lastScrollTop` as part of the component data.
   3, Then, you simply add the scroll event listener in the `mounted()` lifecycle hook, and remove it in the `destroyed()` lifecycle hook.

See updated code below:

```
const options = {
  offset: -50
};

export default {
  name: 'BarMenu',
  data() {
    return {
      scrollingDirection: '',
      lastScrollTop: 0,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    cssClasses() {
      return {
        hidden: this.scrollingDirection === 'down'
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll, false);
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll, false);
  },
  methods: {
    scrollToIngredients() {
      return this.$scrollTo(document.getElementById('ingredients-inside-content'), 600, options);
    },
    scrollToRecipes() {
      return this.$scrollTo(document.getElementById('similar-recipes'), 600, options);
    },
    scrollToComments() {
      return this.$scrollTo(document.getElementById('comments'), 600, options);
    },
    onScroll() {
      let st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      if (st > this.lastScrollTop) {
        this.scrollingDirection = 'down';
      } else {
        this.scrollingDirection = 'up';
      }
      this.lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st;
    }
  },
}
```